# return full list of which element is a member

Tags: mapping, property-lists, alists

i know that `member` returns non-nil if the element is found in the list, but it only returns the tail of the list from element onwards. is there a way to return the full list it is a member of?

my case: i'm iterating over a list of plists, and i want to return the particular plist that contains what i search for (i want to access/use the other info the plist contains).

my solution so far looks like this:

```
 (cl-dolist (child-list parent-list)
   (when (string= (plist-get child-list 'property)
                  "value")
     (cl-return child-list)))
```

is there a more idiomatic way to go about this? the query is not so much `member`? or `-contains?`, as `which-list-contains?`

Comment: Check out `seq-find` (or `seq-filter` if you would like to 'filter' out multiple matching lists)

Comment: @dalanicolai thx for drawing those to my attention. but maybe i'm still missing something: how to construct a predicate that can pass each plist to `plist-get` as an argument (i.e. `child-list` in my example).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: *is there a way to return the full list it is a member of?* The full list is the list you passed to `member`, no? Not too clear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dalanicolai suggested:

```
(seq-find 
  (lambda (plist) 
    (plist-get plist :property)) 
  '((:foo bar) (:baz frob :property quux)))

;; => (:baz frob :property quux)
```